# PostgreSQL - Inserting a combination of values into a table (Example Included)

Tags: postgresql

For example I calculate a predetermined value which is stored in `value`. I would like to insert the value into the table as A100.

I tried doing this at first: `insert into t values('A'+value);`

This didn't seem to work. Does anyone know how I might be able to do this?

Comment: Where does `value` come from? The operator to concatenate character values in SQL is `||`, not `+`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html

Comment: Value is just a variable I created as an iteger. I then for example just did value =0 , value = value +1; Now i just want to join the "value" with the letter A in the begining

Answer (score 1):

You can use `concat` function to do this:

```
insert into t values(concat('A',value::character varying));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [concat](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) or [||](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL)

```
insert into t values(concat('A', value));
insert into t values('A' || value);
```

In both cases You can, but You don't need cast `int` to `character varying`, because `concat`:

> Concatenate the text representations of all the arguments

`||` cast non-string arguments to `text`.